# How to transform text (that contains label and coordinates) in a textbox into a button at indicated coordinates?

Tags: c#, button, textbox

in WindowsForms when I enter a text into my textbox like "button, 100, 200, LABEL" and then I press a button - I would like to work it like a script - e.g. after button pressed I'd like to have a new button at a position (100,200) with the label "LABEL". What would be a solution?

this is for the visual studio 2017

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        insertedText = textBox1.Text;
    }           


    private void executeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoTheButton();
    }

    private void DoTheButton()
    {

        string test = "button,100,200,LABEL";

        int a = Int32.Parse(insertedText);

        if(insertedText==test)
        {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100,200);
        btn.AutoSize = true;
        btn.Text = "open";
            Controls.Add(btn);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong text");
        }
```

Unfortunately, this is not at all a script solution - it just shows a button when I insert the right text - but I'd like to work it as a script.

Answer (score 0):

As for scripts usually, you need to parse a text provided by user into values your program will understand.

In simple case your script takes four arguments separated by comma, where
 (0) is a name of the control type
 (1) is a location.X value
 (2) is a location.Y value
 (3) is a text value

```
private Button CreateFrom(string script)
{
    var values = script.Split(",");
    if (values.Length != 4)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not all values provided", nameof(script));
    }

    if (int.TryParse(values[1], out int x) == false)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("X value is invalid");
    }     

    if (int.TryParse(values[2], out int y) == false)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Y value is invalid");
    }    

    if (string.isNullOrEmpty(values[3]))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Title is empty");
    }    

    var button = new Button 
    { 
        Text = values[3],
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y)
    };

    return button;        
}

private void DoTheButton()
{
    var button = CreateFrom(insertedText);
    Controls.Add(button);
}
```